# How to add legends in ggplot for a curve that derive from another df?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I need to show a series of data points and their mean over-impressed with standard deviation error bars, but I can't manage to impose the legend regarding the mean line, dots and error bars  (so i need 2 legends, the one for the points and another one for the mean).

-here my dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdpVNzw63OaJamvA272WefoTyXIVjaU9/view?usp=sharing

```
#this is my df
sanderia<- read.csv2("Sanderia.csv",header=TRUE)
sanderia$Growth<- as.numeric(sanderia$Growth)
sanderia[,"Treat"]<- as.factor(sanderia[,"Treat"])
sanderia[,"Rep"]<- as.factor(sanderia[,"Rep"])

sanderia

> head(sanderia)
> ID Treat Day Rep Polip Growth Week
> 1  1   T20   1   A    19   1.00    1
> 2  2   T20   2   A    20   1.05    1
> 3  3   T20   3   A    20   1.05    1
> 4  4   T20   4   A    21   1.11    1
> 5  5   T20   5   A    24   1.26    1
> 6  6   T20   6   A    30   1.58    1
sanderia <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Treat = c("T20", "T20", "T20", "T20", "T20", "T20"), Day = 1:6, Rep = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Polip = c(19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 30L), Growth = c(1, 1.05, 1.05, 1.11, 1.26, 1.58), Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

#I calculate mean and sd
df.summary <- sanderia %>%
  group_by(Treat,Day) %>%
  summarise(
    sd = sd(Growth, na.rm = TRUE),
    Growth = mean(Growth)
  )
#note that i call the column of the mean as the column of the data i want to plot, because it's the only way i found to plot it
#so:

> df.summary
> #A tibble: 84 × 4
> #Groups:   Treat [3]
> Treat   Day     sd Growth
> <fct> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1 T10       1 0        1  
> 2 T10       2 0.0300   1.02
> 3 T10       3 0.0943   1.06
> 4 T10       4 0.169    1.15
> 5 T10       5 0.165    1.16
> 6 T10       6 0.219    1.17
> 7 T10       7 0.119    1.12
> 8 T10       8 0.109    1.15
> 9 T10       9 0.156    1.18
> 10 T10      10 0.109    1.15
> #ℹ 74 more rows
> #ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

#now i plot my data:
ggplot(sanderia, aes( x=Day, y=Growth, group=Treat, color=Treat) )+
facet_grid( ~Treat)+
  geom_line(aes(group = Treat), stat = "summary", fun = mean, color="Black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Growth-sd, ymax = Growth+sd), data = df.summary, color="Black")+
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = Growth-sd, ymax = Growth+sd),data = df.summary, color="Black")+
  geom_point()
```

[image: the graphic i obtain]

Comment: The `Treat` legend is for the `color`, what type of aesthetic would the second legend be?

Comment: for the mean, the black line, dots and error bars

Comment: PS. thank you for the edit!!

Comment: Your question is a good start, but given the sample data we have, the resulting base plot is rather lacking, https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp1Rg.png. I recognize you're giving a reduced dataset, is there a way you can give us more data for the single treatment, so that the error bars actually show something? It is sometimes useful to general random data instead of using real data, using a combination of `expand.grid` (across `ID, Treat, Day, Rep, Week`) and then add in random (`runif`?) `Polip, Growth`. With that method, you can create a much larger (if meaningless) dataset that plots how you want

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what I have to do... if you need the full dataset, I will put a link to the CSV file, otherwise, I do not know how to put the entire data frame....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a new `draw_key_errorbar` glyph function (used to draw things in legends), and we'll use the `linetype=` aesthetic to add something to the legends.

```r
draw_key_errorbar <- function(data, params, size) {
    `%||%` <- function(a, b) if (!is.null(a)) a else b # from ggplot2
    if (is.null(data$shape)) {
        data$shape <- 19
    }
    else if (is.character(data$shape)) {
        data$shape <- translate_shape_string(data$shape)
    }
    stroke_size <- data$stroke %||% 0.5
    stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0
    grid::grobTree(
      grid::segmentsGrob(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% 
          data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha), lwd = (data$linewidth %||% 
          0.5) * .pt, lty = data$linetype %||% 1, lineend = params$lineend %||% 
          "butt")),
      grid::linesGrob(c(0.4, 0.6), c(1, 1), gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% 
          data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha), lwd = (data$linewidth %||% 
          0.5) * .pt, lty = data$linetype %||% 1, lineend = params$lineend %||% 
          "butt")),
      grid::linesGrob(c(0.4, 0.6), c(0, 0), gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% 
          data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha), lwd = (data$linewidth %||% 
          0.5) * .pt, lty = data$linetype %||% 1, lineend = params$lineend %||% 
          "butt")),
      grid::pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, pch = data$shape, gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% 
          "black", data$alpha), fill = alpha(data$fill %||% "black", 
          data$alpha), fontsize = (data$size %||% 1.5) * .pt + 
          stroke_size * .stroke/2, lwd = stroke_size * .stroke/2))
    )
}

ggplot(sanderia, aes( x=Day, y=Growth, group=Treat, color=Treat) ) +
  facet_grid( ~Treat) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Treat), stat = "summary", fun = mean, color="Black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Growth-sd, ymax = Growth+sd, linetype = "Error Bar"), 
                key_glyph = draw_key_errorbar,                 # NEW
                data = df.summary, color="Black") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = Growth-sd, ymax = Growth+sd),data = df.summary, color="Black") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = NULL) +                       # NEW, optional
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot with additional legend in the shape of an errorbar]

`draw_key_errorbar` was inspired by https://emilhvitfeldt.com/post/changing-glyph-in-ggplot2, and portions cut from `ggplot2::draw_key_point` and `ggplot2::draw_key_vline`.

---

Data

```r
sanderia <- read.table("https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1cdpVNzw63OaJamvA272WefoTyXIVjaU9&export=download&authuser=0",
                       header = TRUE, sep = ";")
df.summary <- sanderia %>%
  group_by(Treat,Day) %>%
  summarise(
    sd = sd(Growth, na.rm = TRUE),
    Growth = mean(Growth)
  )
```